# WebAPI accepting JWT from client

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

We are working on a new project and the we want to login the user on client side (iOS and Andorid) using Facebook, then generate JWT and send it to the WebApi.

Can we do that and if so, how? If we can do that can we use that JWT to authenticate user in server side?

We want to give ASP.NET MVC Core a chance.

Comment: why you want to generate JWT instead of using Facebook Access Token received after login?

Comment: If I can use it, can u show me how?

Comment: @Set, Facebook Access Token is for accessing facebook resources but as far as i understand Wasyster wants to access own resources. I think generating own access token is reasonable in this case.

Comment: @ademcaglin: It's not. Securely generating a JWT token on the client side is impossible, because you have to sign it. And the Android/iOS are not confidential, so it's impossible to keep it secure.

Comment: @Tseng: You are definitely right, if Waystar wants to generate jwt token on the client side. I didn't understand so. I assumed generating jwt token server side. Maybe my misunderstanding.

Comment: Generating JWT token wasn't my idea ... I tought so that wont be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirements a few weeks ago. My project was to small to use #IdentityServer or something similar.

I solved it using the solution the SimpleTokenProvider https://github.com/nbarbettini/SimpleTokenProvider

This is the blog post about it: https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

If you are not at production stage and willing to manage updates, you can go with [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict).

It's still in alpha stage but support is available on Gitter and it's easy to integrate with jwt middleware.
I am using it in my app too, if you need samples just ask.